# what is the usage of fork while invoke mongod?

Tags: mongodb

```
./mongod –shardsvr –replSet shard1 –port 27017 –dbpath /data/shard12 –fork
```

fork: for server process ( from mongod document).

In plain english, what does fork here mean?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

It starts mongodb as a daemon. Meaning that it will not stop running when you close the terminal.